# JSON Object visible only from side in three.js

Tags: json, three.js, blender

I exported object from blender as .json and rendered it using THREE.js
I selected the checkbox which says Double sided in materials tab in Blender
and also added alfaromeo.doubleSided = true; in my html (alfaromeo is my model name). Still the object is visible only from front side. How do I disable this backface culling?

Comment: Can you access the mesh object created by THREE.js and update its material?  mesh.material.side= THREE.DoubleSide

Comment: I'd also check your camera max distance parameter to make sure the car isn't pivoting out of the camera frustrum. If both @Zagoda 's suggestion and the camera distance looks ok, I'd want to check the integrity of the model and that all the faces are having a material applied.

Comment: @Zagoda I will check if I am already making the doubleSided parameter of my object True and this mesh was created in Blender, not Three.js.

Comment: @Radio How can I check the distance range of the camera? I think it is fine as I can see objects fine but just not the interior/opposite side of the face. I can assure that all the faces have material applied

Comment: I found the answer here. Question also seems like a duplicate. I don't have the permissions to mark this question as duplicate, hence I am placing the link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061271/three-jsonloader-double-sided-texture-png